# How to populate a list of interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, architecture, solid-principles

I am fairly new to the SOLID principles and I have found i often come to the following situation.

I have an implementation of a task that is tied to an interface, when i need to use the class i just use DI for such an interface.

My problem is what to do when i need multiple implementations, for example.

```
List<IDataSource> dataSources = new ArrayList<IDataSource>();
dataSources.add(new DataSourceOne());
dataSources.add(new DataSourceTwo());
.... and so one...
```

then later i will loop over the array to action the interface method for each implementation.

Is this bad practice? is there a way of populating the list without the new keyword? eg c# reflection. or is the a design pattern that avoids this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you got against the `new` keyword when you want to create a new object?

You can simplify the code as:

```
List<DataSource> dataSources = Array.asList(
    new DataSourceOne(),
    new DataSourceTwo(),
    ...
);
```

Although it has some uses, using reflection is almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: That was part of my question really, does doing this count for SOLID?

Comment: @Lunar I think it's "an orthogonal issue". You may want to construct the list before endowing it through a constructor to the object that will use it.